# C++ How to pass an element of an object array by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, reference

I'm trying to pass an array of Coin objects to a Change function that is called from within a user interface function. 
I have tried many combinations of * and & in different places and have found no success.

The user interface function header

```
 void UserInterface (Coin Roll[])
```

The Change function header (tried Coin * coin and got expression must have class type errors)

```
    bool Change ( Coin & coin, long int & mulah )
```

How I am trying to call Change (Roll is an array of Coins) within UserInterface

```
Change(Roll[j], mulah)
```

The whole program is here    http://pastebin.com/6bsuyEvF

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example, **here**.

Comment: What are you trying to pass to `Change`, an array of `Coin` or a `Coin` that is an element of an array?

Comment: @Beta, from his URL, it is array of Coin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was no problem with the code! 
I forgot to add **'&'** to the function prototype *above* int main()

```
bool Change ( Coin & coin, long int & mulah ) ;

int main()
```

{

Needed the address of operator.

Comment: There is no "address of operator" in this code. The `&` is part of declaring a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array as reference like below

```
 void UserInterface (Coin (&Roll)[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities

- `void UserInterface(Coin roll[], int size);`
- `void UserInterface(Coin* roll, int size);`
- `void UserInterface(Coin (&roll)[42]); // size should be 42`
- `template <std::size_t N> void UserInterface(Coin (&roll)[N]);`

Change the accepted type:

- `void UserInterface(std::vector<Coin>& roll);`
- `void UserInterface(std::array<Coin, 42>& roll); // size should be 42`
- `template <std::size_t N> void UserInterface(std::array<Coin, N>& roll);`